# Entity Framework – Inserting into multiple tables using foreign key

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I am a relative newby to EF and have created a simple model (see below) using EF4.
[image]

I am having a problem inserting a new record into the UserRecord entity and subsequently adding the UserDetail entity which uses the newly created UserRecordId as its primary key. The code shown below used to work when my database had a one-to-many relationship but when I change this to a one-to-one relationship I get the error highlighted in the image below. 
[image]

I believe its not working as there is now no UserDetails property associated with the UserRecord because it’s  now a one-to-one relationship. My question is how do I now insert new UserRecord and corresponding UserDetail entities with a one-to-one relationship?

Any help on this one is much appreciated as have been on searching the web and trying a variety of different things without success.

Cheers

Cragly

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your `UserDetail` object should have a property that links back to the `UserRecord` object. (It is maybe called `User`? If I'm reading the navigation section below correctly.) If you set that property to your new, uncommitted `UserRecord` object, it will automatically fill in the key when it commits both objects.

```
UserRecord userRecord = new UserRecord();
// whatever

UserDetail userDetail = new UserDetail();
userDetail.User = userRecord; // This will auto-fill the FK during commit.
// whatever

// Add both userRecord and userDetail to the context and commit.
```

Comment: Fantastic!! Thanks very much works brilliantly. Looks like I was trying to do it the wrong way round and looking to add UserDetails to UserRecord rather than the other way round. You saved me some more hair loss which I can save until I hit my next brick EF wall!

Comment: Yea. I tried this many other ways in my system, including an attempt at a two-phase commit. This is the only thing that worked for me, and it's exceptionally elegant and intuitive to boot.