# Insert into multiple tables using ado.net entity object

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-4

I want to insert records in multiple tables with entity framework 4.0

My database contains 2 tables

```
 1. Student (StudentID - PrimaryKey)
 2. Standard (StudentID - ForeignKey)
```

How can I add values into these table at one time?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442915/entity-framework-inserting-into-multiple-tables-using-foreign-key

Comment: thanks Abi but i not getting exact idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
Student student = new Student();
...
Standard standard = new Standard();
standard.Student = student;

/* Commit it */
```