# Inserting a dependent entity when inserting a parent with Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

I am having an issue inserting a record for a dependent entity when inserting the parent. Below is my entity definitions and mappings

EBUser

```
public partial class EBUser : ModelBase, IUser<long>
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public long AccountId { get; set; }
    public EBAccount EbAccount { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastUpdateDate { get; set; }

    public virtual EBUserInfo UserInfo { get; set; }
}
```

EBUserInfo

```
public partial class EBUserInfo : ModelBase
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public virtual EBUser User { get; set; }
}
```

EBUserMapping

```
public class EBUserMapping : BaseEntityMapping<EBUser>
{
    public EBUserMapping()
    {
        this.ToTable("Users");
        this.Property(u => u.AccountId).HasColumnName("AccountId");
        this.Property(u => u.Password).HasColumnName("Password");
        this.Property(u => u.UserName).HasColumnName("UserName");
        this.Property(u => u.Email).HasColumnName("Email");
        this.Property(u => u.CreatedDate).HasColumnName("CreatedDate");
        this.Property(u => u.LastUpdateDate).HasColumnName("LastUpdateDate").IsOptional();

        //this.HasRequired(u => u.UserInfo).WithRequiredDependent(u => u.User);
        this.HasRequired(t => t.EbAccount)
            .WithMany(t => t.Users)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.AccountId);
    }
}
```

EBUserInfoMapping

```
public class EBUserInfoMapping :BaseEntityMapping<EBUserInfo>
{
    public EBUserInfoMapping()
    {
        this.ToTable("UserInfo");
        this.Property(u => u.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
        this.Property(u => u.Email).HasColumnName("Email");
        this.Property(u => u.FirstName).HasColumnName("FirstName");
        this.Property(u => u.LastName).HasColumnName("LastName");
        this.Property(u => u.DisplayName).HasColumnName("DisplayName");

        // Relationships
        this.HasRequired(t => t.User).//WithRequiredDependent(t => t.UserInfo);
        WithOptional(t => t.UserInfo);
    }
}
```

In the database schema, all tables have an ID column but in the `EBUserInfor` class the `Id` column is both the primary and foreign key to the `EBUsers` table.

The `BaseEntityuMapping` maps the `Id` column and set the `DatabaseGenerationOptions` to `identity` but in the `EBUserinfoMapping` class I overwrite that with a `DatabaseGenerationOption` of `None`.

When I insert a new `EBUser` record using Entity Framework, the user record is created but no `userInfo` record is created

Please help

Thanks

Comment: Why did you abandon the `WithRequiredDependent(t => t.UserInfo)` part? That's exactly the mapping you need here.

Comment: That's the first property I set but the UserInfor dependent still did not insert, when the User object was inserted. I am now thinking I need to insert the UserInfo object and let Entity Framework auto insert the principal. I will try that and update this thread if it works

Comment: Nope did not work using    WithRequitedDependent or WithOptional

Comment: Well, I don't see what you do exactly and what "doesn't work" means. The *only* mapping between the two should be `this.HasRequired(t => t.User).WithRequiredDependent(t => t.UserInfo)` (or WithOptional).

Comment: "doesn't work" means the userInfo record is not created when I save the user object. The userInfo object is hydrated when I retrieve the user object from the context and user object is hydrated when i retrieve the userInfo object. When I try to insert the user object, the userinfo object is not persisted and when I try to the insert the userInfo object, it fails because ef does not attempt to create the user object first to get the Id which will be used for the userInfo object primary key, so inserting the userinfo object fails to insert for a foreign key violation

Answer (score 0):

Map user to userInfo as

```
EBuser user= new EBuser();
// fill here user
EBuserInfo info = new EBuserInfo();
Info.userInfo= user;
// fill here rest info
db.add(info);
db.saveChanges();
```

Comment: So add the dependent entity instead of the principal to the context for the both records to be created in the database?

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work. Looking at the generated SQL, only the insert statement for the dependent entity was generated (UserInfo), cause a foreign key constraint violation because the id was 0 and cannot be an identity column

Comment: From view when your save userRecored action called then you have to map those values of model which is coming from the view to the entities which are genrated by entity framework. At controller you have to map the user data into the userinfo.user property which is of user type. So first map all values in the user entity from view and then put that user into userinfo.user entity add finally save it.

Comment: Please refer this link, same as your scenerio http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442915/entity-framework-inserting-into-multiple-tables-using-foreign-key  hope it will go you through the problem.

Comment: According to the post, I have to create instances of bother dependent and principal entities, assigned the principal to a navigation property of the the dependent and then add both dependent and principal to the context before saving. Is this an accurate assessment?

Comment: Are you using code first approach or database first? Yes this is what you have understood from linked post. Try creating default project template and can see how this work when you register a user and its roles inserted in user role table.

Comment: I suggest you to create two table in your database with foregin keys and try to create a project with database first with entity framework and then use scanfold to genrate crud operation.

Comment: Code first. I used Entity Framework power tools to reverse engineer the models and mappings. I should mention I implemented a repo pattern and all saves and commits are using generic types